# Is there a limit to zip-on-zip compression?

Tags: compression, zip

I recently made a 10.5GB file of all zeroes, and started zipping and duplicating it, similar to a zip bomb. The compression per-layer was:

- 1<sup>st</sup> layer (the 10.5GB file): very high compression (about 35MB)
- 2<sup>nd</sup> layer (64 zipped raw files): very high compression (about 6MB)
- 3<sup>rd</sup> layer (64 zipped 2<sup>nd</sup> layer files): very high compression (about 5MB)
- 4<sup>th</sup> layer (64 zipped 3<sup>rd</sup> layer files): moderate compression (about 105MB)
- 5<sup>th</sup> layer (64 zipped 4<sup>th</sup> layer files): Unknown error

This was from using Linux's zip program.

Is there a limit to the compression of .zip? From attempting to create the 5th layer, it seems like there is one.

Comment: More likely you hit a filesystem or OS limitation.

Comment: what is the "_raw file_"?

Comment: what do you mean "_is there a limit_"? Are you asking if there is a limit to zip-within-zip? To total archive size (compressed / plain)?

Comment: I also struggle to believe that 64x 6MB files compresses to 5MB - A) zipping a zip file isn't going to achieve much as the data is already compressed (making it hard to compress further) B) even with good de-dupe, you're looking at a minimum of "_6MB + a bit_"

Comment: Please also share the commands you are running for each step.

Comment: @Attie I just used the Compress> .zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit. Sadly, zip-on-zip does not generally produce smaller files. Your particular case of an all zero file is an unusual exception. It wouldn't work on 10gb of random or "typical" file data for example.